# pandas-how can I replace rows in a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, replace, rows

I am new in Python and try to replace rows.

I have a dataframe such as:

| X | Y |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | a |
| 2 | d |
| 3 | c |
| 4 | a |
| 5 | b |
| 6 | e |
| 7 | a |
| 8 | b |

I have two question:

1- How can I replace 2nd row with 5th, such as:

| X | Y |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | a |
| 5 | b |
| 3 | c |
| 4 | a |
| 2 | d |
| 6 | e |
| 7 | a |
| 8 | b |

2- How can I put 6th row above 3rd row, such as:

| X | Y |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | a |
| 2 | d |
| 6 | e |
| 3 | c |
| 4 | a |
| 5 | b |
| 7 | a |
| 8 | b |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First use [`DataFrame.iloc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html), python counts from `0`, so for select second row use `1` and for fifth use `4`:

```
df.iloc[[1, 4]] = df.iloc[[4, 1]]
print (df)
   X  Y
0  1  a
1  5  b
2  3  c
3  4  a
4  2  d
5  6  e
6  7  a
7  8  b
```

And then `rename` indices for above value, here `1` and sorting with only stable sorting `mergesort`:

```
df = df.rename({5:1}).sort_index(kind='mergesort', ignore_index=True)
print (df)
   X  Y
0  1  a
1  2  d
2  6  e
3  3  c
4  4  a
5  5  b
6  7  a
7  8  b
```

Comment: Thank you very much!  I have not write "ignore_index=True" because  I have an error if I write it. Error is: "TypeError: sort_index() got an unexpected keyword argument 'ignore_index'" I don't know why